# Two compiled binary files with exactly same assembly code behaves differently while cracking binary file ? Or may be i am missing something?

Tags: diff, reverse-engineering, patch, cracking, ghidra

I have two exe files one is original file and another one is cracked exe file of software [Vector magic](https://vectormagic.com/desktop/download) and cracked file is [vmbe.zip](https://github.com/threatrack/ghidra-patchdiff-correlator/files/4794943/vmde.zip)
Both files have exactly same size.

I am using ghidra to decompile those binary files 
Then i just export those files to format c/c++ program by just using option *File->Export Program (O)*

then i open those files into Visual studio and apply *Diff* extention to find difference between those files and i can navigate to differences by just pressing *ALT+F5*

Then i observed that some functions just failed to decompiled showing following error but i just search those functions in Ghidra by using *Windows->Functions* and again i decompiled those functions one by one and then put those functions into overall .c file at appropriate positions.

```
/*
Unable to decompile 'FUN_004475d0'
Cause: Exception while decompiling 004475d0: process: timeout
*/
```

Now i have two .c files one is decompiled version of original exe file and another one is of cracked exe file 
and after fixing fewer variables names we can easily find that there is only one difference between those two files at the end of function `FUN_0043a620`

**Original exe's decompiled .c file**

```c
    _bVar2 = uVar3 & 0xffffff00 | (uint)bVar2;
  }
  *in_FS_OFFSET = local_c;
  return _bVar2;
}
```

**Cracked exe's decompiled .c file**

```c
    _bVar2 = uVar3 & 0xffffff00 | 1;
  }
  *in_FS_OFFSET = local_c;
  return _bVar2;
}
```

And in Ghidra we can see there is just one assembly instruction is changed at Memory location `0043a687`

**Original file**

```
        0043a687 b3  01           MOV        BL,AL
```

**Cracked file**

```
        0043a687 b3  01           MOV        BL,0x1
```

Now i changed that instruction in original exe file and just export binary file from option *File->Export Program (O)*

Then i try my version of cracked binary file by just replacing ogrinal file with my cracked file and it just don't work but when i try cracked file it work like a charm.

And this patch is just looks like a correct solution because this is the function that decides weather the software is registered or not by just observing returned value and we just make it to always `return 1`. We can search uses of that function `FUN_0043a620` in decomplied .c file 
For example

```c
 if (local_65 != 0) {
    uVar5 = FUN_0043a620();
    if ((char)uVar5 != '\0') {
      pQVar7 = (QString *)FUN_0043a580((char *)&local_54,"Thank you for activating!");
      local_4._0_1_ = 5;
      pQVar8 = (QString *)FUN_0043a580((char *)&param_1,"Activation succeeded");
```

And

```c
 uVar4 = FUN_0043a620();
  if ((char)uVar4 == '\0') {
    pQVar5 = (QString *)
             FUN_0044b910((char *)&local_14,

                          "Not activated. Click the \'Activate\' button on the first page to enable saving."
                         );
```

That exacly what i was discovered even before looking at cracked binary and i tried it but it did not worked then i find this cracked file tried to understand differences between working cracked binary vs original binary.

### I want to know why my cracked version not working even i copied exact changed assembly instruction from working cracked file ?

Comment: I would recommend using hex editors (FlexHex, BeyondCompare, ...) and look for differences between the two files, maybe there are other differences that are not code differences, for example - some changes in global data.

Comment: thank you for you reply. i check and there are only 4 bytes that are changed. But i am not good at binary. i am unable to figure about that those 4 bytes are doing !

Comment: i also changed that 4 bytes and It works like cham. any suggestions for how can i know what those 4 bytes are doing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use hex editors (FlexHex, BeyondCompare, ...) and look for differences between the two files, maybe there are other differences that are not code differences, for example - some changes in global data.

In order to understand what are those other bytes, you can analyze the binary either

1. statically: Open it in `Ghidra` or `IDA` and look for x-refs to this data, and where it used. Good chance it is somehow related to the other change that you saw in the code.
2. dynamically: Try to set Hardware breakpoint on access to this location.

Comment: Got it.
i was facing a problem to locate address shown in HeX editor and Ghidra and i figured out that in HeX editor it starts from 000000 and in Ghidra it starts from 00400000. Why is that ?

Comment: addresss `0043a687` is changed in ghidra as mensioned in question and this address is in HeX editor is `0003a687` which is `0043a687`-`0040000`